# How to shorten this if and elif code in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring

There are two variables, `a` and `b`, and each can either be positive or negative. An identifier needs to be set based on the four conditions. How could I minimize the code given below so that the same task could be achieved? A list comprehension or bitwise operation or something along those lines might shorten this, but I have no idea how to do this.

```
if a > 0 and b > 0:
    direction = 'NORTH EAST'

elif a > 0 and b < 0:
    direction = 'SOUTH EAST'

elif a < 0 and b < 0:
    direction = 'SOUTH WEST'

elif a < 0 and b > 0:
    direction = 'NORTH WEST'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional expressions like this

```
("NORTH " if b > 0 else "SOUTH ") + ("EAST" if a > 0 else "WEST")
```

There is one more hack which can be used here

```
["SOUTH ", "NORTH "][b > 0] + ["WEST", "EAST"][a > 0]
```

This works because, in Python [boolean values are actually integers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values). The following are true in Python

```
print 1 == True
# True
print 0 == False
# True
```

Comment: That last option is definitely a hack; explicit is better than implicit, and the implicit `int` values of `bool` are always a surprise to newcomers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried to explain a bit, and included the doc page corresponding to this. Does this look okay now?

Comment: Zen of Python must include 'Elegance beats everything!' as is clearly demonstrated here!

Comment: @thefourtheye: I am talking about the fact that it needs an explanation at all, which is why I would avoid it.

Comment: @user3058846: it does: *Readability counts* and *Beautiful is better than ugly*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional expressions:

```
direction = ' '.join(['NORTH' if a > 0 else 'SOUTH',
                      'EAST' if b > 0 else 'WEST'])
```

Demo:

```
>>> for a in (-1, 1):
...     for b in (-1, 1):
...         print ' '.join(['NORTH' if a > 0 else 'SOUTH',
...                         'EAST' if b > 0 else 'WEST'])
... 
SOUTH WEST
SOUTH EAST
NORTH WEST
NORTH EAST
```

Answer (score 0):

Your's looks fine.  Here is the same thing using a conditional expression:

```
>>> 
>>> a = 1
>>> b = -1
>>> lat = 'NORTH' if a > 0 else 'SOUTH'
>>> lon = 'EAST' if b > 0 else 'WEST'
>>> direction = '{} {}'.format(lat, lon)
>>> direction
'NORTH WEST'
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like I was slow on the draw again.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a dictionary as a map

```
map[-1] = {-1:'SOUTH WEST', 1: 'NORTH WEST'}
map[1] = {-1:'SOUTH EST', 1: 'NORTH EST'}
direction = map[a/abs(a)][b/abs(b)]
```

Comment: you are overwriting built-in map() this way, not the best name for variable

Comment: true, I realized just after posting the answer